# Re-using the activity

Tags: android

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Home.class);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
break;
```

I am trying to re-use my `activity` like this, but the activity is not getting opened at all. Below is my `Android-Manifest.xml` code for the corresponding `activity`.

```
<activity android:label="Home" 
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:name="com.test.Home">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.Home" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Is it a good practice to re-launch the existing `activity`. I don't want it to get re-used in all cases only some situations, so tried the above Intent code.

Comment: have you `activity.startActivity(intent);` ??? You are only creating an intent :/

Comment: @PaNaVTEC: should i tbe startActivity(intent) or activity.startActivity(intent)... as its throwing me when i do activity.startActivity(intent)

Comment: you need to use startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add it to you `manifest file` where you have declared your activity

It will create only single instance of your activity.
after first creation when ever you will call this activity its `onResume` function will be called instead of `onCreate`. hence you will be able to use the same activity
without creating it again and again

```
android:launchMode= "singleInstance"
```

or You can try adding the  Flag

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)
```

it will bring back the already created activity to front instead of of creating new instance

open the acitivty

like this

```
Intent i= new Intent(myactivity1.this,myactivity2.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: why should i pass two instance of my activity to Intent

Comment: I am passing the only one instance to intent...
first one is current activity in which currently I am "myactivity1"

second one is the activity that i want to open "myactivity2 "

Comment: If i am opening the activity from a fragment class, then should i use getActivity()

Comment: Does fragment class means you are trying to open it from some class which actually do not extend activity(hence you are not able to access start activity there) ?

Comment: If i use getActivity(), then there should be no problem as such right

Comment: Yes u can use getActivity ()